# convergence of the p-adic log in $pZ_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, formal-completions

I've been trying to solve the following problem:

Show that the series $\log(1 + x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} x^n/n$ converges on $p\mathbb{Z}_p$ with respect to $|.|_p$ (p-adic absolute value). Show that for any positive integer $n$, $v_p(n!) < n/(p - 1)$.

I tried to prove that the sequence of residues, i.e., $\{\sum_{n = m}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} x^n/n\}_{m \to\infty}$ converges to $0$ but I couldn't do it. I believe I am missing something obvious here. Thanks!

Comment: Not a dupe, but related discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48620/11619). See David Loeffler's answer in particular. Well, Lord Shark gives a nice argument for the basic result.

Comment: It's probably worth learning Legendre's formula, $v_p(n!)=\frac{n-s_p(n)}{p-1}$, here $s_p(n)$ is the sum of digits of $n$ in base $p$. since it keeps popping up when dealing with convergence of series in p-adic analysis. In particular, it simplifies the inequality $v_p(n!)<\frac{n}{p-1}$ for any positive integer $n$ to $s_p(n)>0$ which is clearly true, the sum of any digits of a positive number is again positive.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570481/p-adic-logarithm-log-p1-x-p-x-p/1570561)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over the $p$-adics, because of the ultrametric property, to show that a series
$\sum_n a_n$ converges all that's required is to prove that $a_n\to0$.
It is I hope clear that $v_p(n)\le\log_pn$ (this is the usual real logarithm to base $p$ not a $p$-adic logarithm). Thus
$$v_p(x^n/n)\ge n-\log_pn\to\infty$$ 
for $x\in p\Bbb Z_p$. That is, $x^n/n\to0$ $p$-adically. This then implies that
the series for the $p$-adic logarithm converges.

Answer (score 5):

Given a P-adic field $k$, with $p=P^e$, write $v$ for $v_p$ such that $v_P$ = $e\cdot v_p$. Then:

1. The series $\log(1+x)$ converges for $v(x) >0$ : If $p^r \le n <p^{r+1}, v(x^n/n)=nv(x )- v(n) \ge n v(x)-r$, which implies elementarily that $v(x^n/n) \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ when $v(x)>0$. This shows the ultrametric convergence.
2. $v(n!)<n/(p-1)$ : Write $n$ in basis $p$, i.e. $n=a_0+a_1p+...+a_rp^r$, where $a_i\in \mathbf Z$ and $0\le a_i \le p-1$. Then \begin{align} &[n/p]=a_1+a_2p+...+a_rp^{r-1} \\ &[n/p^2]=a_2+...+a_rp^{r-2} \\ &~~~~~~~~~~~~\vdots \\&  [n/p^r]=a_r \end{align}But clearly $v(n!)=[n/p]+[n/p^2]+...+[n/p^r]=a_1+(1+p)a_2+...+(1+p+...+p^{r-1})a_r$, so that $(p-1)v(n!)=0+(p-1)a_1+(p^2-1)a_2+...+(p^r-1)a_r=n-(a_0+a_1+...+a_r)$. This shows the desired inequality.